# how do i correct no row at position 0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

i want to build a multiuser window form but whenever i run code i get the error

> there is no row at position 0

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-LAI8526\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=user_dt;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from lgn_table where user_id='" + textBox1.Text + "'and user_psd='" + textBox2.Text + "' and user_type='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select user_type from lgn_table where user_id='" + textBox1.Text + "'and user_psd='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                sda1.Fill(dt1);
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "admin")
                {
                    Form2 f = new Form2();
                    f.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "employee")
                {
                    Form1 d = new Form1();
                    d.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: as the error is there is no row @ index 0 then i would suggest adding a row before accessing it, this is probably because the query returns no data

Comment: Note that your code is very susceptible to SQL Injection since you are not using parameterized queries.

Comment: What is `user_psd`??? I hope it's not a password. Storing passwords, much less storing them in cleartext, shouldn't be done even in sample and toy projects. And yes, it's trivial to hack this code. Passing `' or 1=1` as the password would allow everyone to log in. Passing `'; drop table lgn_table;` would delete the table

Comment: Ah, yes. Little Bobby Tables: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Why did you tag this as `c#-2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

trying changing to

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
    return;
```

this will exit the function if there are no rows

Comment: Small remark @MikeT you return without opening the followup dialog Form1 or Form2. I think the user will appreciate a MessageBox.Show(...) with a meaningful warning !